# Unpack python tuple with [ ]'s

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

I know the canonical way to unpack a tuple is like this

```py
a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
# or
(a,b,c) = (1, 2, 3)
```

but noticed that you can unpack a tuple like this

```py
[a, b, c] = (1, 2, 3)
```

Does the second method incur any extra cost due to some sort of cast or list construction? Is there a way to inspect how the python interpreter is dealing with this akin to looking at the assembly from a compiler?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, those are all exactly equivalent. One way to look at this empirically is to use the `dis` dissasembler:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("(a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3)")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("[a, b, c] = (1, 2, 3)")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ((1, 2, 3))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

From the formal language specification, this is [detailed here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). This is part of the "target list", A relevant quote:

> Assignment of an object to a target list, **optionally enclosed in
> parentheses or square brackets,** is recursively defined as
> follows....

Comment: Nice explanations and `dis` analysis.

Answer (score 7):

Using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) and selecting `Python` as the language then entering the three lines of code, you can see they all have the same bytecode:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 2, 3))
              2 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
              4 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
              8 STORE_NAME               2 (c)

  2          10 LOAD_CONST               6 ((1, 2, 3))
             12 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
             14 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             18 STORE_NAME               2 (c)

  3          20 LOAD_CONST               7 ((1, 2, 3))
             22 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          3
             24 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
             26 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             28 STORE_NAME               2 (c)
```

So, they are the same, just different syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the execution time and number of cycles using Linux perf tools. All 3 programs are showing the same execution time, so I think there are not any extra costs.